# Using curl to upload video to DailyMotion, all requests returning successful but video still not uploaded

Tags: dailymotion-api

I have implemented the following Bash script with which I'm trying to upload videos to my Dailymotion account. All the `curl` requests return JSON responses as listed on the official API documentation pages. However, my video fails to show up in my account. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash


    curl -s --output out.txt --data 'grant_type=password&client_id=<My-ID>&client_secret=<My-Secret>&username=<My-Username>&password=<My-password>&scope=read+write' https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token

    var1=$(grep "access_token" out.txt | cut -d: --complement -f1)
    acc_token=$(echo $var1 | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d\" --complement -f1 | cut -d\" -f1)

    curl -s --output out.txt -i https://api.dailymotion.com/file/upload?access_token="$acc_token"        
    upload_url=$(grep "upload_url" out.txt | cut -d: --complement -f1 | cut -d\" --complement -f1 | cut -d\" -f1 | sed 's/\\//g')

    curl -s --output out.txt -F 'file=@/home/zahaib/video.mp4' "$upload_url"
    video_url=$(grep "url" out.txt | cut -d: --complement -f1-10 | cut -d\" --complement -f1 | cut -d# -f1 )

    curl -s --output out.txt -d $video_url https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos?access_token="$acc_token"
    video_id=$(grep "id" out.txt | cut -d: --complement -f1 | cut -d\" --complement -f1 | cut -d\" -f1 )

    curl -s --output out.txt -d 'title=Vid&channel=sport&tags=was' https://api.dailymotion.com/video/"$video_id"/access_token="$acc_token"
    curl -s --output out.txt -d 'published=true' https://api.dailymotion.com/video/"$video_id"/access_token="$acc_token"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your script on the last two lines:

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/"$video_id"/access_token="$acc_token"
```

Instead of:

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/"$video_id"/?access_token="$acc_token"
```

It's right there, in your out.txt:

```
{
    "error":{
        "code":501,
        "message":"Invalid method name: POST \/video\/<xid>\/access_token=<redated>.",
        "type":"invalid_method"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I made the changes but still the videos fail to show up in the list of my videos. I think I may not be treating the response returned by the `curl -F 'file=@/home/zahaib/video.mp4' "$upload_url" ` correctly. The JSON returns a url field which has a hash (#) and then a long train of characters. I'm not sure if I should truncate the URL at the hash or  include the entire train of characters in the `$video_url`.

Comment: Everything that is returned is part of the upload URL.

Comment: great! it works now. I'm probably gonna make this available via Github as well, in case anyone wants a simple Bash script to upload videos.